# How to serve different url with one file in nginx

Tags: nginx, docker-container

I use docker container to serve an html and some other files. there is no back-end website. I just server some static files.

I need to point some different url to one folder.

I have one index.html file in /usr/share/nginx/html.

I want to point all ulr like:

```
 / , /a , /a/b/c , /a/
```

to the same:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html file.
```

my nginx config is as below :

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location /lalala/ {
        proxy_pass http://lalalalalala/;
    }

    location /proxy/bebebebe/ {
        proxy_pass https://www.bebebebe.com/;
    }

    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

I try to use alias like this:

```
location / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index  index.html index.htm;
  alias /a /usr/share/nginx/html
  alias /b /usr/share/nginx/html      
  alias /a/b/c /usr/share/nginx/html
}
```

But it's not work.

Comment: You can try `rewrite ^(/a|/b/|/a/b/c)/?$ /;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try_files` to look for a specific file and return `index.html` if that file is not found.

For example:

```
location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.